# Can`t set up $watch of attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-animate

I was creating simple example of angular animation based on element,class and attribute directive. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/Tw2dAGQJqoUy2sOOdoJr?p=preview

I`ve set up a variable and animate it change

```
<body ng-init="myValue=0">
```

In case of attribute, i tried to watch not for the variable, but for the attribute

In html:

```
<div my-dir3 = {{myValue}}></div>
```

In script.js:

```
scope.$watch(attr.myDir3, function(newVal) {...}
```

But it doesn`t works(except page openning).

Can you give me explanation, why? Or maybe some links for explaining the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, but you should use `$observe` instead like :

```
attr.$observe('myDir3', function(val) {
    //change
});
```

Here is your updated <kbd>[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ntNvnfZLjXz63PlMnkQD?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought, i tried it, but it doesnt helped those time))